# s3 bucket name as part os subdomain but not hosting a website, just proxy

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy

I want to be able to access my bucket as `bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com` instead of `s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname` so that I can easily setup a DNS redirect to it.

Is the best (only?) way to do that to set up the s3 bucket as a website?

[image: AWS Console for bucket]

Answer (score 0):

> so that I can easily setup a DNS redirect to it

That isn't exactly how it works.  Simply pointing DNS to the hostname of a bucket does not cause the bucket to respond to requests for that hostname.

In order to point a hostname to a bucket in DNS, you have two options:

You can create a bucket named *exactly* the same as the hostname -- for example, if you want to point images.example.com to a bucket, the actual name of the bucket must be `images.example.com`. (Option 1)

Or, you can create a CloudFront distribution, point it to the bucket, set the desired hostname as an Alternate Domain Name on the CloudFront distribution, and point your DNS to CloudFront.  In this configuration,  the bucket name doesn't matter. (Option 2)

Only option 2 supports SSL.

Enabling the web site hosting feature is only indirectly related to what you are trying to do -- this will enable features like redirects and index documents, and will also change the endpoint you need to map to, into a format similar to `example-bucket.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com` (depending on the bucket region) and this value will be displayed in the console.  You'll need this for either your DNS settings (option 1, above) or your CloudFront configuration (this will be your origin domain name, option 2, above).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand option 1.  the bucket should actually be named "images.example.com"? (Currently, the bucket is named something like, "appImageBucket" Does using a domain name as a bucket name do something? [Thanks!]

Comment: @nycynik using a domain name as the bucket name is **required** if you want the bucket to respond to requests for that hostname (and you aren't using CloudFront).  HTTP has no awareness of CNAMEs. The web server must be configured to expect the same hostname that appears in the browser's address bar.  With S3, the way that works is by matching that incoming `Host:` header to the bucket name:   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: Dots in a bucket name are only good for this purpose.  Otherwise, you don't want them -- if you want to use the built-in S3 SSL certs on the REST endpoints, or you want to use transfer acceleration, dots are not allowed in the bucket name.  Note also if you are really using something like `appImageBucket` with capital letters in it -- you should also reconsider that.  Mixed case names and bucket names longer than 63 characters are both deprecated features and aren't allowed in most regions.  See [Bucket Restrictions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html).